# R: summarise data frame with repeating rows into boxplots

Tags: r, dataframe

I am an R neophyte, with a data frame of database function runtimes with the following data:

```
> head(data2)
              dbfunc runtime
1 fn_slot03_byperson  38.083
2 fn_slot03_byperson  32.396
3 fn_slot03_byperson  41.246
4 fn_slot03_byperson  92.904
5 fn_slot03_byperson 130.512
6 fn_slot03_byperson 113.853
```

The data has data for 127 discrete functions comprising of some 1940170 rows.

I would like to:

1. Summarise the data to only include database functions with a mean runtime of over 100 ms
2. Produce boxplots of the 25 slowest database functions showing the distribution of runtimes, sorted by slowest first.

I'm particularly stumped by the summary step.

Note : I've also asked this questions at [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13138/summarise-data-frame-with-repeating-rows-into-boxplots).

Comment: Please don't crosspost to multiple stackexchange sites.

Comment: Not only that but I just addressed a rather similar question on rhelp. I suggested code using `tapply` and `aggregate`, and have seen no followup.

Comment: Apologies to both of you. The post on stats.stackexchange was closed as it wasn't deemed generally relevant to stats. The solutions you provided on the R mailing list, DWin, error with "Error in aggregate.data.frame(data2, data2$function., FUN = mean) : 
  'by' must be a list"

Comment: DWin: Your solution for adding a mean column works well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rorycl I requested that the stats.stackexchnage post be closed as OT. In future note that it is possible to migrate posts from one SE site to another, thus even less reason to crosspost; the community can decide which is the most appropriate venue for the Q and it and any Answers and comments can all be migrated to that venue. If you hadn't crossposted I would have requested the mods Migrate your Q as there is nothing wrong with it other than being OT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using `ggplot` and `plyr`. The steps you outlined could be combined to be slightly more efficient, but for learning purposes I'll show you the steps as you asked them.

```
#Load ggplot and make some fake data
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(dbfunc = rep(letters[1:10], each = 100)
                  , runtime = runif(1000, max = 300))

#Use plyr to calculate a new variable for the mean runtime by dbfunc and add as 
#a new column
dat <- ddply(dat, "dbfunc", transform, meanRunTime = mean(runtime))

#Subset only those dbfunc with mean run times greater than 100. Is this step necessary?
dat.long <- subset(dat, meanRunTime > 100)


#Reorder the level for the dbfunc variable in terms of the mean runtime. Note that relevel
#accepts a function like mean so if the subset step above isn't necessary, then we can simply
#use that instead.
dat.long$dbfunc <- reorder(dat.long$dbfunc, -dat.long$meanRunTime)

#Subset one more time to get the top *n* dbfunctions based on mean runtime. I chose three here...
dat.plot <- subset(dat.long, dbfunc %in% levels(dbfunc)[1:3])

#Now you have your top three dbfuncs, but a bunch of unused levels hanging out so let's drop them
dat.plot$dbfunc <- droplevels(dat.plot$dbfunc)

#Plotting time!
ggplot(dat.plot, aes(dbfunc, runtime)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Like I said, I feel a few of those steps could be combined and made more efficient, but wanted to show you the steps as you outlined them.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. It is hugely helpful. I installed ggplot via install.packages; I had to get ggplot2 for my version of R. On the plotting step I get the following error:ggplot2::ggplot(dat.plot, aes(dbfunc, runtime)) + ggplot2::geom_boxplot() no applicable method for 'ggplot' applied to an object of class "data.frame".

Comment: @rorycl `ggplot` is a colloquial term for `ggplot2`.

Comment: @rorycl - I apologize for being misleading there, you do in fact need ggplot2 so looks like you're on the right path. I'm not terribly familiar with the error code you posted, can you update your question above to include more details about the error? specifically, `str(dat.plot)` and anything that led to the error?

Comment: @Chase -- apologies. Presently on holiday without machine without ggplot install

Comment: @Chase -- now got it working by reinstalling ggplot. Wonderful graphics, although I can only get 10 boxplots on a screen, and the labels only show the first letter of the function names. > str(dat.plot)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ dbfunc     : Factor w/ 10 levels "e","a","b","i",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ runtime    : num  234.1 42 263.3 85.3 141.6 ...
 $ meanRunTime: num  155 155 155 155 155 ...
$menRunTime looks incorrect if it is by function. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The summary step is easy:

```
attach(data2)
func_mean = tapply(runtime, dbfunc, mean)
```

ad question 1:

```
func_mean[func_mean > 100]
```

ad question 2:

```
slowest25 = head(sort(func_mean, decreasing = TRUE), n=25)
sl25_data = merge(data.frame(dbfunc = names(slowest25), data2, sort = F)
plot(sl25_data$runtime ~ sl25_data$dbfunc)
```

Hope this helps. Yet the boxplots are not sorted in the plot.

Comment: Hi Tomas. Thanks very much for this. Constructing and filtering func_mean into slowest25 is cool. Thanks very much for that. I couldn't do the sl25_data step as 'data2' doesn't exist. I've tried replacing that with the original data frame but that didn't work -- I need an x/y matrix for the first argument to data.frame. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as the 'answer' whereas Tomas and Chases' answers are in fact more complete. In Chase's case I couldn't get ggplot to operate, and time was short. In Tomas' case I got stuck at the sl25_data step.

We ended up using the following, which works with one remaining problem:

```
# load data frame
dbruntimes <- read.csv("db_runtimes.csv",sep=',',header=FALSE)
# calc means
meanruns <- aggregate(dbruntimes["runtime"],dbruntimes["dbfunc"],mean)
# filter
topmeanruns <- meanruns[meanruns$runtime>100,]
# order by means
meanruns <- meanruns[rev(order(meanruns$runtime)),]
# get top 25 results
drawfuncs <- meanruns[1:25,"dbfunc"]
# subset for plot
forboxplot <- subset(dbruntimes,dbfunc %in% levels(drawfuncs)[0:25])
# plot
boxplot(forboxplot$runtime~forboxplot$dbfunc)
```

This gives us the result we are looking for, but all the functions are still shown on the plot xaxis, rather than just the top 25.